# Android Studio failure to recognize switch case values

Tags: android

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    switch (action)
    {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            return true;

        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    int THIS_CODE_WORKS = event.getActionMasked();
    String s = "";
    switch (THIS_CODE_WORKS)
    {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            s="down";
            Log.v("Action",s);
            break;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
```

Even though the debugger shows that the action variable = 2, the case statement for MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE (2) is ignored.  The default statement always executes.  This is sample code from Google, yet it does not work. I cannot figure out why the statements are not evaluated as expected.

Comment: are you sure? Try to put some log statements.

Comment: Updated.  Added the THIS_CODE_WORKS line and below with the modified case statement.  I guess it didn't like having only a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getAction()` and change your switch case

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            // finger touches the screen
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // finger moves on the screen
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
            // finger leaves the screen
            break;
    }

    //handled the event and no further processing is required
    return true; 
}
```